# SonarQube api api/project_analyses/search fails with 403 "msg": "Insufficient privileges" yet API key user is admin

Tags: api, sonarqube, http-status-code-403

I am accessing the SonarQube API through API key as described in https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extension-guide/web-api/

- A call to /api/components/search_projects works.
- A call to `/api/project_analyses/search?project=PJ` fails with http error code 403

If I log into the web interface with that user, I can browse the statistics. In fact Chromes F12 debug shows that it's calling the same api function `/api/project_analyses/search` yet with session cookie, xrfs-token etc. and the call succeeds.

What am I missing to be able to retrieve project statistics through the API?

Comment: Can you check the token used is created by the user which has sufficient permission for the project **PJ** ??

Comment: After changing the token type to user and the user having sufficient rights, the API query works. I would  accept your answer.

Comment: Let me write the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token used is created by the user which has sufficient permission for the project `PJ`

You need to check the permission and generate new token accordingly.